# Вылетает приложение при повоторе экрана

Tags: android

При повороте телефона находясь в MainActivity приложение вылетает и выдает такое эксепшн

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    ExpandableListView expList;
    DBHeler db;
    ExpListAdapter adapter;
    final private static int LOADER = 1;
    private int currentLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = new DBHeler(this);

        String[] groupFrom = { Contract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME };
        int[] groupTo = { android.R.id.text1 };

        String[] childFrom = { Contract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME };
        int[] childTo = { android.R.id.text1  };

        adapter = new ExpListAdapter(
                this,
                null,
                R.layout.item_group, // разметка корневых айтемов
                groupFrom,
                groupTo,
                R.layout.item, // разметка вложенных айтемов
                childFrom,
                childTo);

        expList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expList);
        expList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expList.setAdapter(adapter);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        expList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dish.class);
                long id = l;
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });

        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(currentLoader, null, this);
    }


    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        DBHeler dbHeler;
        final int loaderID;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHeler dbHeler, int id) {
            super(context);
            this.dbHeler = dbHeler;
            loaderID = id;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor onLoadInBackground() {
            return dbHeler.getCategory();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.changeCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.changeCursor(null);
    }

}
```

Код для БД

```
public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            //получаем путь до БД вместе с именем.
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor getSingleDost(long id) {
        return this.getReadableDatabase().query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_DOST, null, Contract.Entry._ID + " = "
                + id, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getFavoritesDost() {
        return database.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_DOST, null, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITE + " = 1",
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getCategory() {
        return this.getReadableDatabase().query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_CATEGORY, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getDost(long categoryID) {
        return this.getReadableDatabase().query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_DOST, null, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORYID + " = "
                + categoryID, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // база не существует
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Ошибка

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM category
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:151)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:123)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:236)
at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter$MyCursorHelper.moveTo(CursorTreeAdapter.java:446)
at android.widget.CursorTreeAdapter.getGroupView(CursorTreeAdapter.java:196)
at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2934)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1945)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:719)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:785)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1721)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2728)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1375)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1193)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1742)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:344)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:281)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17972)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5814)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2370)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1440)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7421)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventRec
```

Какая может быть причина?

Comment: Согласно ошибке `IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM category` вы пытаетесь делать запрос в БД через мёртвое соединение с оной.

Comment: А как это исправить? У меня в ExpandbleListView выводится информация из БД через адаптер. В другом приложении для обычного ListView почти также все реализовано, но там такого нет.

Comment: Ну... Покажите код инициализации БД и делания запроса к ней - может кто-то что-то увидит. Код инициализации адаптера лишним также не будет

Comment: В `DBHelper` нужно `return this.getReadableDatabase().query()` заменить на `return database.query()` в методах `getCategory()`, `getDost()`, `getSingleDost()`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую как буду у компьютера.

Comment: все равно вылетает с такой же ошибкой

Comment: В `onResume()` вместо `currentLoader` нужно `getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER, null, this);`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас нет ошибки.